# Android create child "Activity" similar to pushing UIViewController

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In an iOS View I can create a UIViewController, create and bind SubViews to that (child) UIViewController and Push it onto the back stack.

I have an existing app that currently uses Activities in Android and in one of those Activities I want to instantiate a "Child Page"

Should I be looking to use Fragments for this in Android?

I had a look at fragments and my initial thought was for that to work I needed to be working with Fragments from the first View as I need to be setting them up against a Container.

Answer (score 0):

"I have an existing app that currently uses Activities in Android and in one of those Activities I want to instantiate a "Child Page"

I am not 100% sure what you mean exactly by "child page". You can start a new activity from an existing activity and then you can use the back button to get back to the first activity. The second activity could be called a "child page" but if so, it would seem you have already done this since you say "I have an existing app that currently uses Activities."

However I think that fragments might be what you are looking for if you want to stay in the same Activity but show a different page. It might be helpful for you to go over Xamarin's guide on using fragments: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/fragments_walkthrough/

Comment: By "Child Page" I meant a Page\View that was instantiated by the current Activity, populated by the current Activity and shown by an event being fired in that Activity. If I start an Activity from the current Activity can I create sub views in that Activity before displaying it?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to do that in the OnCreate method of the activity (or fragment if you go the fragment route). The OnCreate fires before the Activity/fragment is displayed. Look over the Android lifecycle for more info.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html , https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle